# Cannot get environmental variables in Python sometimes?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

So I have a Django/Python 3.4.3 setup with nginx, gunicorn and postgres on Ubuntu Server 14.04. The server is blank and setup following this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04). I have set a few environmental variables in the `/etc/environment` as follows and rebooted:

```
DJANGO_DB_NAME="db"
DJANGO_DB_USER="username"
DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD="password"
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="9g2&ionu!4u@%@2f&(r0dpp_yplyukxde^*1+evf7ko#_yn6%h"
```

So from Django's settings.py file I try to access it in a variety of ways, but ran into unexpected behavior:

```
'NAME': os.getenv('DJANGO_DB_NAME') # this works correctly
'NAME': os.environ.get('DJANGO_DB_NAME') # this works correctly
'NAME': os.environ['DJANGO_DB_NAME'] # this does NOT work and yields 'key' does not exist
```

None of these works as it returns an empty string instead of the key value:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY']
```

Django Error:

```
  File "/webapps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 120, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
```

From within Ubuntu, when I access the environment variables from the command line, I always get the correct result back:

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01:/webapps#  echo $DJANGO_SECRET_KEY
9g2&ionu!4u@%@2f&(r0dpp_yplyukxde^*1+evf7ko

root@ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01:/webapps# echo $DJANGO_DB_USER
username
```

Yet, when I do this from command line it works!

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01:/webapps# python3 -c "import os; print(os.environ['DJANGO_SECRET_KEY'])"
9g2&ionu!4u@%@2f&(r0dpp_yplyukxde^*1+evf7ko
```

Now, I am really confused. Any expert know what is going on and how to solve this?

**Update 1:** per comments by m.wasowski, gunicorn is running as root and running manage.py runserver works just fine again as root. Gunicorn only complains when I run 'service gunicorn start'. Security issues as running as root, or storing key in environment is temporary until I just get it working first.

Comment: `os.getenv` literally calls `os.environ.get`, and `os.environ` is just a “better dictionary”, so `os.environ.get(key)` is the same as `os.environ[key]` (if the key exists). So something odd is going on here.

Comment: environment can be different for different users. Root has different environment than user you are running django with. Try running your server like `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="foo" python manage.py runserver`. Generally, not the best idea to store secret keys in `/etc/environment`, let alone posting them.

Comment: @m.wasowski: Gunicorn is running as root, and running manage.py runserver works. I'm starting this with lax settings to test, and then one by one, I will reconfigure it to be user/permission specific to each service/process. Key will be regenerated later. Thanks for the tip though.